# Why this code compile but crash when run?

Tags: java, compilation, crash

Consider the following code:

```
public class foo{
    static class Node{
        Object item;
        Node next;
        Node(Object item, Node next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node data = null;
        data = new Node("hello", data);
        data = new Node(5, data);
        while (data!=null){
            String s = (String) data.item;
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a multiple-choice question and the answer is "this code will compile successfully but crash when run."
Why?
Where does it crash?

Comment: `data` never changes. So if the loop is entered it will never be exited

Comment: @GBlodgett That's an endless loop, though, not a crash.

Comment: should not be to hard to just test it....

Answer (score 3):

**First**, You are casting `data.item` to `String`. This will produce:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

**Second**, Variable data is never updated inside of the loop, just like @GBlodgett pointed out.

```
while (data != null){
    String s = (String) data.item;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```